# How to javascript call iframe loaded file function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have this code on index.html

```
<body>
    <iframe id=iframetest src="alt.html">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
             document.getElementById('iframetest').contentWindow.myFunction();
        });
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

and this 1 is in alt.html

```
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //When click on the button function will run
        function myFunction(){
        alert("Hello World");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
```

i want to display alert in index.html. but this was not worked.how can i do this? pleas help me

thank you!

Comment: I think document.getElementById('iframetest').contentWindow.myFunction(); is correct but it doesn't work on all browsers and is a bit unstable.

Comment: Did you try window.frames['iframetest'] where name is the name of your iframe (change it to <iframe name="iframetest">?

Answer (score 3):

This is considered more reliable and might work:

```
<body>
    <iframe name=iframetest src="alt.html">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
             window.frames['iframetest'].myFunction();
        });
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction();">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Here's [a link](http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/) that will explain it.

also make sure alt and index.html are within the same domain using the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)

Comment: Why is that more reliable? Do you have a link to more information? Your point about the potential cross-domain issue is valid though

Comment: Because it is an older interface and more likely to be supported by all browsers. Updated answer with link